# Can I repurpose generator wiring for EV charging?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I currently have a professionally installed (and inspected) portable generator inlet installed on the side of my house. It is wired to a 30A breaker in the main panel and has an interlock. I don't need this generator inlet anymore as I've since had a whole house generator installed that has its own sub panel/transfer switch. Can I simply remove the interlock and remove/rewire the inlet to an EVSE? I realize that removing an interlock isn't something that should ever be done however this is a permanent change and none of this will ever be used for a generator again. I know I'd be restricted to 24A given the 30A breaker but I'm ok with that, I don't need super fast charging. Just trying to see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: You would probably need to remove the interlock to hardwire the EVSE to the panel(to get around needing a GFCI).

Comment: If you want to be *picky* about it, remove the inlet **first**, and then removing the interlock has not even a whiff of hinkiness about it. Also check the wire size/material - some folks choose a larger than minimum wire in case they might upsize the generator later on. You could get lucky with that, or not.

Comment: @crip659 The interlock is totally unrelated to hardwire vs. receptacle. The interlock has to be removed so that the repurposed circuit can be powered while the main is on.

Comment: @nobody  I did mess up.  Was thinking inlet, but somehow wrote interlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Replace the inlet with a hard-wired outdoor-rated EVSE and remove the interlock at the panel.

You need to do load calcs to make sure your service and panel both have capacity for a new 24A load.  If not, you can buy a smaller charger, replace the breaker with an appropriately smaller one, but use the existing cable from the inlet.

You'll have a spare white wire at the inlet, just cap it there.  You can leave it alone in the panel.

Your "never remove an interlock" rule is reasonable so long as there is a generator inlet but not after it's removed.

Comment: The vast majority of EVSEs allow a DIP switch setting or procedure to select the charge ampacity.  This procedure must be difficult to do casually during ordinary use, per UL/CSA. Many cars and some EVSEs also allow a soft setting easily done from the driver's seat or an app, but that does not meet the requirement.

Comment: @Jason if you already bought the charger, and if you must and can limit it as noted in the above comment, that would be *preferable* to buying a smaller one and you don't need to change the breaker.

Comment: That's right. The EVSE ("charger") setup instructions will say to set the breaker size, but you can just set the breaker you *should* have based on the Load Calc... and that's fine. The breaker size only needs to be small enough for the wire, in case the EVSE itself has a problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The EVSE is adjustable, I'd be setting it based on my current breaker size.

Comment: @JasonP the point is, do a Load Calculation to determine what load the panel can handle. The generator breaker is no help here, since a generator is an anti-load.   Feel free to consider an EVEMS such as the WallBox, which puts clamp meters on your supply wires to dynamically adjust charge rate to assure your panel is never overloaded.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I did do a load calculation. I'm well under my 200A service.